# Does it make sense to create many Maven parent poms based on project types?

Tags: java, maven, build

I am trying to understand what would be the best way to organize Maven projects. 
Let's say I have these projects -

- ProjectA - webapp, uses Spring MVC
- ProjectB - util library1,
  uses logging, snakeyml
- ProjectC - util library2, uses logging,
  snakeyml
- ProjectD - DAO library, uses logging, uses Spring annotations

A depends on D, D depends on C. B doesn't depend on anything.

I created a parent-pom project with snakeyml, slf4j and log4j as dependencies. I declared this project as parent in B, C and D poms. The parent pom also defines compiler specific properties.

My understanding is that when you declare something as a parent, Maven's inheritance in poms allows the child projects to inherit all the dependencies. If this is correct, should I have multiple parent poms? Let's say, just like parent-pom, should there be a parent-spring-pom, which all spring projects will inherit from? Is this a good practice to have so many different parents, just to have better organization of dependencies, but no logical project hierarchy? Also, I am not declaring the child projects as modules in parent, because some of them are independent libraries. Am I deviating too much from Maven conventions?

Comment: Sharing dependency declarations is a double-edged sword. Maybe your dependencies are the same today, but what are you going to do tomorrow when they diverge? I'm not a maven expert, but I'd say keep your project hierarchy simple and don't fret over repeated dependency declarations.

Answer (score 3):

You should not group your projects by the technology used but by their function.

Let's say you now consider creating a parent project `parent-spring-pom` which will have as child Spring projects. What if tomorrow you decide to switch from Spring to JSF? Or a home-grown framework? Worse, you want to switch one of the projects and not all of them? You will have to change the name of every module and *this is a pain*. The name given to something should not be about *how* but about *what*.

This is also true in the context of Maven and multi-module projects.

Note that in your use-case, I don't see the added value of having multiple parents. I feel it complexifies the project more than anything. But you could for example group projects by web-apps, core utilities, data accesses...

Just as an example, consider you have a data-access layer that accesses multiple endpoints (e.g. a web service and a database). It could make sense to group them in a common parent named `project-dao` and have modules `project-dao-wsclient` (that will contain the specific code for accessing the web service) and `project-dao-db` (that will contain the specific code for accessing the database).